# Tensor derivative

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

What is the result of
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \left(A^{ij}y^ix^j+B^{ij}x^iy^j\right)}{\partial \bf x\partial \bf y}
$$
where $i,j$ obey Einstein summation convention, $A,B$ are constant, ${\bf x}=[x^1,x^2,\dots,x^n]^{\rm T}$, and ${\bf y}=[y^1,y^2,\dots,y^n]^{\rm T}$. Here 
$$
A^{ij}y^ix^j=A^{11}y^1x^1+A^{12}y^1x^2+\dots+A^{1n}y^1x^n+\dots+A^{nn}y^nx^n
$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial \lambda}$ is denoting an outer product of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ with $\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}$ we have

$$
\begin{align}
\partial_{x^m} \partial_{\lambda^n} (A^{ij} \lambda^i x^j + B^{ij} x^i \lambda^j)
&= A^{ij} \delta^{in} \delta^{jm} + B^{ij} \delta^{im} \delta^{jn} \\
&=A^{nm} + B^{mn}
\end{align}
$$

so the result is $A^\top + B$ (or its transpose depending on which index is the row index).

If $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial \lambda}$ is denoting a contraction of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ with $\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}$ we set $n = m$ in the previous result and the result is $\mathrm{tr}(A) + \mathrm{tr}(B)$.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, what does the $\delta$ mean?

Comment: [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) tensor: $\delta^{ij}$ equals $1$ for $i = j$ and $0$ otherwise. In particular, $\partial_{x^m} x^n = \delta^{mn}$.